# count of records in a streamsets stage

Tags: streamsets

I use Streamsets to ingest records from oracle to ElasticSearch. I want to register in maprDB destination the count of record that I process each step in my oracle query. How can I get the number of records at a certain streamsets stage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert one of the script processors (JavaScript Evaluator) to trigger event record. And connect MaprDB destination to script processor event lane.

```
var eventRecord = sdcFunctions.createEvent("count", 1);
eventRecord.value = { recordCount :  records.length};
sdcFunctions.toEvent(eventRecord);
```

[Sample Pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBDxM.png)